# RouterModule is imported in HomeModule when it should be imported via SharedModule as SharedModule is exporting it

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

```
import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared'; 
const homeRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild([
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  } 
]);
@NgModule({
    imports: [
       homeRouting,
      SharedModule
 ],
    declarations: [
       HomeComponent
 ],
    providers: []
 })
export class HomeModule {}


import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
@NgModule({
    imports: [
      CommonModule,
      FormsModule,
      ReactiveFormsModule,
      HttpModule,
      RouterModule
  ],
    declarations: [],
    exports: [
       CommonModule,
       FormsModule,
       ReactiveFormsModule,
       HttpModule,
       RouterModule
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

SharedModule already exports RouterModule and HomeModule imports SharedModule then RouterModule should be impicitely available then why RouterModule is imported explicitely in HomeModule ? .

Answer (score 0):

Inside `SharedModule`, import `RouterModule.forChild()`. 
Inside `AppModule`, import `RouterModule.forRoot(...)`.

The static `forRoot` method allows the Router services to be registered with the Root injector. It a required module for Routing to work because it registers the Router services as singletons, and makes the routes available throughout your app.